# Query to show if a customer bought the same artictle on the same day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say i have a table SALES

```
Date         ArticleID  CustomerID SalesID
2016-04-01      4          1000      1
2016-04-01      8          1000      2
2016-04-01      4          1000      3
2016-04-01      12         1000      4
2016-04-02      4          1000      5
2016-04-03      6          800       6
2016-04-03      4          1000      7
2016-04-05      99         900       8
2016-04-06      4          700       9
```

My Goal is to make a query that Returns only the rows where the same Customer bought the same Article on the same Day.

In this case, result should be:

```
Date         ArticleID  CustomerID SalesID
2016-04-01      4          1000      1
2016-04-01      4          1000      3
```

How do i write this query the best way? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerID, Date, ArticleID
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY CustomerID, Date, ArticleID
    HAVING COUNT(SalesID) >= 2
)a
    ON a.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
    AND a.Date = t.Date
    AND a.ArticleID = t.ArticleID
```

Another method is to use `COUNT OVER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        cnt = COUNT(SalesID) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID, Date, ArticleID)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    Date, ArticleID, CustomerID, SalesID
FROM Cte
WHERE cnt >= 2
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482496)</kbd>

Comment: Beat me to the edit :-) I was going to post pretty much the same thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [group by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [having](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx), and then join to the original table:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Date, ArticleId, CustomerId
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Date, ArticleId, CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(SalesId) > 1
)

SELECT S.Date, S.ArticleId, S.CustomerId, S.SalesId
FROM Sales S
INNER JOIN CTE C ON(S.Date = C.Date AND S.ArticleId = C.ArticleId AND S.CustomerId = C.CustomerId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query

```
select date,articleid,customerid,salesid from sales 
inner join 
(select date,articleid,customerid 
from sales 
group by date,articleid,customerid 
having count(1)>1) b
on sales.date=b.date
and sales.articleid=b.articleid
and sales.customerid=b.customerid
```

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery to do this.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable AS A INNER JOIN (
SELECT Date, ArticleID, CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfCount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date, ArticleID, CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) >1 ) AS B
ON A.Date = B.Date
AND A.ArticleID = B.ArticleID
AND A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COUNT()` with `OVER` in following:

```
select Date_, ArticleID, CustomerId, SalesID
from (select *, 
             count(*) over(partition by Date_, ArticleID, CustomerId) cnt 
      from #t )x
where cnt > 1
```